# URL Rewriting with a ? symbol

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I try to re-write a URL that have this form:

website.com/?q=home

to this form:

website.com/home

I cannot find.

I tried this form for example: 
RewriteRule ^\?q\=home$  /home [R=301,L]

Looks like the "?" or the "=" are posing problem? Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: 5 questions and you haven't accepted any answers? You should work on marking answers that solve your problem as 'accepted' (big checkmark) so that others will a) know which answer helped with your problem, and b) will want to help you in the future.

Comment: I can't find the big checkmark, didn't know there is a way to accept an answer, will check it out

Comment: okey found it thanks Phrogz ;)

Answer (score 1):

Everything after the `?` is in the variable `%{QUERY_STRING}`.

To rewrite just the value `home` use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=home$
RewriteRule ^ /home? [L,R=301]
```

To rewrite all `q` values to static URIs use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
```

The last ? in the RewriteRule removes the query string from the target URI.

Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)